# rsync and changing destination files to hardlinks

Tags: rsync

I have two hard disks mounted at `src/` and `tgt/` respectively. There are a enough hard links in `src/` that `rsync -a src/ tgt` made the destination disk run out of space. I have learnt that I should have additionally used the `-H` option so that hard links in `src/` become hard links in `tgt/`.

If I run `rsync -aH src/ tgt` now, will distinct files in `tgt/` that are instead hardlinks in `src/` be converted to hardlinks in `tgt/` so that the disk doesn't run out of space?

(The clearest option seems to be to delete the contents of `tgt/` and run rsync again with `-H`, but I am curious.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are considering deleting `tgt` anyway, why don't you try running `rsync` with `-H` to see what happens?

The hard links will be created and space will be saved.

Comment: Yes, this is a good point.